# SQL Pivoting table using date as columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

How can I get this table:
[image] 
Too Look something like this: [image]
I have tried pivots but am unable to use so far, guessing because the ItemID column is a varchar column.
Here is what I have so far with sample data:

```
    IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#TempSupplierDemands') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE #TempSupplierDemands

  DECLARE @VEN varchar(10)
  SET @VEN = '10161';

  DECLARE @VenRecordID as VARCHAR(MAX)
  SET @VenRecordID = 
  (SELECT VEN_RecordID
  FROM VEN
  WHERE VEN_VENDORID = @VEN)

  CREATE TABLE #TempSupplierDemands(
  VendorID NVARCHAR(100),
  ItemID VARCHAR(MAX),
  ItemDescription VARCHAR(MAX),
  MondayWeekStart DATETIME,
  SDM_DemandDate DATETIME,
  SDM_DemandWeek INT)

  INSERT INTO #TempSupplierDemands (VendorID,ItemID,ItemDescription,MondayWeekStart,SDM_DemandDate,SDM_DemandWeek) VALUES ('10161','0AMB000940','CONN ROD/BRG ASSY, 21 CFM','2017-03-20 00:00:00.000','2017-03-24 00:00:00.000','12');
INSERT INTO #TempSupplierDemands (VendorID,ItemID,ItemDescription,MondayWeekStart,SDM_DemandDate,SDM_DemandWeek) VALUES ('10161','0AMB000508','PLATE, OIL PUMP ASSY W/OPS','2017-03-27 00:00:00.000','2017-03-29 00:00:00.000','13');
INSERT INTO #TempSupplierDemands (VendorID,ItemID,ItemDescription,MondayWeekStart,SDM_DemandDate,SDM_DemandWeek) VALUES ('10161','0AMB000198','CRANKCASE, ASSY, 3 CYL REED','2017-03-27 00:00:00.000','2017-03-29 00:00:00.000','13');
INSERT INTO #TempSupplierDemands (VendorID,ItemID,ItemDescription,MondayWeekStart,SDM_DemandDate,SDM_DemandWeek) VALUES ('10161','0AMB000374','CONNECTING ROD MACH, 24 CFM 116 LG','2017-03-27 00:00:00.000','2017-03-29 00:00:00.000','13');
INSERT INTO #TempSupplierDemands (VendorID,ItemID,ItemDescription,MondayWeekStart,SDM_DemandDate,SDM_DemandWeek) VALUES ('10161','06DA507674','TERM PLATE, 5 PIN','2017-03-27 00:00:00.000','2017-03-29 00:00:00.000','13');
INSERT INTO #TempSupplierDemands (VendorID,ItemID,ItemDescription,MondayWeekStart,SDM_DemandDate,SDM_DemandWeek) VALUES ('10161','06DA405234','CONNECTING ROD ASSY (4,6 CYL)','2017-04-10 00:00:00.000','2017-04-10 00:00:00.000','15');
INSERT INTO #TempSupplierDemands (VendorID,ItemID,ItemDescription,MondayWeekStart,SDM_DemandDate,SDM_DemandWeek) VALUES ('10161','06DA405234','CONNECTING ROD ASSY (4,6 CYL)','2017-04-10 00:00:00.000','2017-04-11 00:00:00.000','15');
INSERT INTO #TempSupplierDemands (VendorID,ItemID,ItemDescription,MondayWeekStart,SDM_DemandDate,SDM_DemandWeek) VALUES ('10161','1TU0502','MOTOR CASE - MACHINED','2017-04-10 00:00:00.000','2017-04-13 00:00:00.000','15');
INSERT INTO #TempSupplierDemands (VendorID,ItemID,ItemDescription,MondayWeekStart,SDM_DemandDate,SDM_DemandWeek) VALUES ('10161','1TA0915D','CASING, OUTLET(4.0/2.8)','2017-04-17 00:00:00.000','2017-04-18 00:00:00.000','16');
INSERT INTO #TempSupplierDemands (VendorID,ItemID,ItemDescription,MondayWeekStart,SDM_DemandDate,SDM_DemandWeek) VALUES ('10161','1BZB002222','MOTOR CASE MACHINING, FRAME 2','2017-04-17 00:00:00.000','2017-04-18 00:00:00.000','16');
INSERT INTO #TempSupplierDemands (VendorID,ItemID,ItemDescription,MondayWeekStart,SDM_DemandDate,SDM_DemandWeek) VALUES ('10161','1BZB003224','OUTLET CASE MACHINING','2017-04-17 00:00:00.000','2017-04-18 00:00:00.000','16');
INSERT INTO #TempSupplierDemands (VendorID,ItemID,ItemDescription,MondayWeekStart,SDM_DemandDate,SDM_DemandWeek) VALUES ('10161','1BZB003226','IRA BEARING COVER MACHINING','2017-04-17 00:00:00.000','2017-04-18 00:00:00.000','16');
INSERT INTO #TempSupplierDemands (VendorID,ItemID,ItemDescription,MondayWeekStart,SDM_DemandDate,SDM_DemandWeek) VALUES ('10161','1BZB003228','IRA DISCHARGE COVER MACHINING','2017-04-17 00:00:00.000','2017-04-18 00:00:00.000','16');
INSERT INTO #TempSupplierDemands (VendorID,ItemID,ItemDescription,MondayWeekStart,SDM_DemandDate,SDM_DemandWeek) VALUES ('10161','1BZB003205','ROTOR CASE MACHINING','2017-04-17 00:00:00.000','2017-04-18 00:00:00.000','16');
INSERT INTO #TempSupplierDemands (VendorID,ItemID,ItemDescription,MondayWeekStart,SDM_DemandDate,SDM_DemandWeek) VALUES ('10161','1BZB003126','IRA BEARING COVER MACHINING','2017-04-17 00:00:00.000','2017-04-19 00:00:00.000','16');
INSERT INTO #TempSupplierDemands (VendorID,ItemID,ItemDescription,MondayWeekStart,SDM_DemandDate,SDM_DemandWeek) VALUES ('10161','1TA0915D','CASING, OUTLET(4.0/2.8)','2017-04-17 00:00:00.000','2017-04-19 00:00:00.000','16');
INSERT INTO #TempSupplierDemands (VendorID,ItemID,ItemDescription,MondayWeekStart,SDM_DemandDate,SDM_DemandWeek) VALUES ('10161','1BZB003128','IRA DISCHARGE COVER MACHINING','2017-04-17 00:00:00.000','2017-04-19 00:00:00.000','16');
INSERT INTO #TempSupplierDemands (VendorID,ItemID,ItemDescription,MondayWeekStart,SDM_DemandDate,SDM_DemandWeek) VALUES ('10161','0AMB000508','PLATE, OIL PUMP ASSY W/OPS','2017-04-17 00:00:00.000','2017-04-19 00:00:00.000','16');
INSERT INTO #TempSupplierDemands (VendorID,ItemID,ItemDescription,MondayWeekStart,SDM_DemandDate,SDM_DemandWeek) VALUES ('10161','0AMB000198','CRANKCASE, ASSY, 3 CYL REED','2017-04-17 00:00:00.000','2017-04-19 00:00:00.000','16');
INSERT INTO #TempSupplierDemands (VendorID,ItemID,ItemDescription,MondayWeekStart,SDM_DemandDate,SDM_DemandWeek) VALUES ('10161','0AMB000374','CONNECTING ROD MACH, 24 CFM 116 LG','2017-04-17 00:00:00.000','2017-04-19 00:00:00.000','16');
INSERT INTO #TempSupplierDemands (VendorID,ItemID,ItemDescription,MondayWeekStart,SDM_DemandDate,SDM_DemandWeek) VALUES ('10161','1BZB003105','ROTOR CASE MACHINING','2017-04-17 00:00:00.000','2017-04-19 00:00:00.000','16');
INSERT INTO #TempSupplierDemands (VendorID,ItemID,ItemDescription,MondayWeekStart,SDM_DemandDate,SDM_DemandWeek) VALUES ('10161','1BZB003122','MOTOR COVER MACHINING','2017-04-17 00:00:00.000','2017-04-19 00:00:00.000','16');

declare @cols varchar(max)


SELECT @cols = COALESCE (@cols + ',[' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, [MondayWeekStart], 106) + ']', 
               '[' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, [MondayWeekStart], 106) + ']')
               FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT [MondayWeekStart] FROM #TempSupplierDemands) PV  
               ORDER BY [MondayWeekStart]

declare @query varchar(max) 

select @query = 'select *
from 
(
  select VendorID,ItemID, ItemDescription ,MondayWeekStart
  from #TempSupplierDemands
) src
pivot
(
  COUNT(ItemID)
  for MondayWeekStart in (' + @cols + ')
) piv;'


execute(@query)
```

Comment: Can you post the PIVOT That you tried to use so I can try to modify it or tell you if I see any problems?  PIVOTs can be tricky.

Comment: it also helps if you post your data as structured text instead of images so that I can quickly copy/paste it to test my answer instead of having to retype that garbage row for row.  Also, some people can't view image links at work and image links can be broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the input from your image, I solved it with the use of dynamic sql. Hope it's clear to you.

```
CREATE TABLE #T (ItemID VARCHAR(255), ItemDesc VARCHAR(255), MondayWeekStart DATE, SDM_DemandDate DATETIME, SDM_DemandWeek INT)
INSERT INTO #T VALUES
('0AMB000940','CONN ROD/BRG ASSY, 21 CFM','2017-03-27 00:00:00.000','2017-03-31 00:00:00.000','12'),
('0AMB000508','PLATE, OIL PUMP ASSY W/OPS','2017-04-03 00:00:00.000','2017-04-05 00:00:00.000','13'),
('0AMB000198','CRANKCASE, ASSY, 3 CYL REED','2017-04-03 00:00:00.000','2017-04-05 00:00:00.000','13'),
('0AMB000374','CONNECTING ROD MACH, 24 CFM 116 LG','2017-04-03 00:00:00.000','2017-04-05 00:00:00.000','13'),
('06DA507674','TERM PLATE, 5 PIN','2017-04-03 00:00:00.000','2017-04-05 00:00:00.000','13'),
('06DA405234','CONNECTING ROD ASSY (4,6 CYL)','2017-04-17 00:00:00.000','2017-04-17 00:00:00.000','15'),
('06DA405234','CONNECTING ROD ASSY (4,6 CYL)','2017-04-17 00:00:00.000','2017-04-18 00:00:00.000','15'),
('1TU0502','MOTOR CASE - MACHINED','2017-04-17 00:00:00.000','2017-04-20 00:00:00.000','15'),
('1TA0915D','CASING, OUTLET(4.0/2.8)','2017-04-24 00:00:00.000','2017-04-25 00:00:00.000','16'),
('1BZB002222','MOTOR CASE MACHINING, FRAME 2','2017-04-24 00:00:00.000','2017-04-25 00:00:00.000','16'),
('1BZB003224','OUTLET CASE MACHINING','2017-04-24 00:00:00.000','2017-04-25 00:00:00.000','16'),
('1BZB003226','IRA BEARING COVER MACHINING','2017-04-24 00:00:00.000','2017-04-25 00:00:00.000','16'),
('1BZB003228','IRA DISCHARGE COVER MACHINING','2017-04-24 00:00:00.000','2017-04-25 00:00:00.000','16'),
('1BZB003205','ROTOR CASE MACHINING','2017-04-24 00:00:00.000','2017-04-25 00:00:00.000','16'),
('1BZB003126','IRA BEARING COVER MACHINING','2017-04-24 00:00:00.000','2017-04-26 00:00:00.000','16'),
('1TA0915D','CASING, OUTLET(4.0/2.8)','2017-04-24 00:00:00.000','2017-04-26 00:00:00.000','16'),
('1BZB003128','IRA DISCHARGE COVER MACHINING','2017-04-24 00:00:00.000','2017-04-26 00:00:00.000','16'),
('0AMB000508','PLATE, OIL PUMP ASSY W/OPS','2017-04-24 00:00:00.000','2017-04-26 00:00:00.000','16'),
('0AMB000198','CRANKCASE, ASSY, 3 CYL REED','2017-04-24 00:00:00.000','2017-04-26 00:00:00.000','16'),
('0AMB000374','CONNECTING ROD MACH, 24 CFM 116 LG','2017-04-24 00:00:00.000','2017-04-26 00:00:00.000','16'),
('1BZB003105','ROTOR CASE MACHINING','2017-04-24 00:00:00.000','2017-04-26 00:00:00.000','16'),
('1BZB003122','MOTOR COVER MACHINING','2017-04-24 00:00:00.000','2017-04-26 00:00:00.000','16')

CREATE TABLE #W  (WeekStart DATE)
INSERT INTO #W VALUES
('20170313'),('20170320'),('20170327'),('20170403'),('20170410'),('20170417'),('20170424'),('20170501')

DECLARE @StartDate DATE, @EndDate DATE
SET @StartDate = DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 0) --Monday of current week
SET @EndDate = (SELECT MAX(WeekStart) FROM #W)

DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX), @PvtColumns VARCHAR(MAX), @IsNullPvtColumns AS VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @PvtColumns = substring(
                    (
                        Select ',['+ CAST(w.WeekStart AS VARCHAR(255)) + ']' AS [text()]
                        From #W AS w
                        Where w.WeekStart >= @StartDate AND w.WeekStart <= @EndDate
                        For XML PATH ('')
                    ), 2, 4000)

SET @IsNullPvtColumns = substring(
                    (
                        Select ',ISNULL(['+ CAST(w.WeekStart AS VARCHAR(255)) + '], 0) AS [' + CAST(w.WeekStart AS VARCHAR(255)) + '] ' AS [text()]
                        From #W AS w
                        Where w.WeekStart >= @StartDate AND w.WeekStart <= @EndDate
                        For XML PATH ('')
                    ), 2, 4000)

SET @Sql = 'SELECT pvt.ItemId, pvt.ItemDesc, ISNULL(bkl.Backlog, 0) AS Backlog, ' + @IsNullPvtColumns + ' FROM ( '
SET @Sql = @Sql + 'SELECT ItemId, ItemDesc, w.WeekStart, SDM_DemandWeek FROM ' 
SET @Sql = @Sql + '(SELECT WeekStart FROM #W WHERE WeekStart >= '''+ CAST(@StartDate AS VARCHAR(255)) + ''' AND WeekStart <= '''+ CAST(@EndDate AS VARCHAR(255))+''') AS w  LEFT OUTER JOIN #T AS t ON w.WeekStart = t.MondayWeekStart ) AS r '
SET @Sql = @Sql + 'PIVOT ' 
SET @Sql = @Sql + '(SUM(SDM_DemandWeek) FOR r.WeekStart IN ('+ @PvtColumns +')'
SET @Sql = @Sql + ') AS pvt '
SET @Sql = @Sql + 'LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT ItemId, SUM(SDM_DemandWeek) AS Backlog FROM #T WHERE SDM_DemandDate < '''+ CAST(@StartDate AS VARCHAR(255)) + ''' GROUP BY ItemID, ItemDesc) AS bkl '
SET @Sql = @Sql + 'ON bkl.ItemId = pvt.ItemId '
SET @Sql = @Sql + 'WHERE pvt.ItemId IS NOT NULL '
SET @Sql = @Sql + 'ORDER BY pvt.ItemID '

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Result

```
ItemId      ItemDesc                            Backlog  2017-04-24  2017-05-01
0AMB000198  CRANKCASE, ASSY, 3 CYL REED         13       16          0
0AMB000374  CONNECTING ROD MACH, 24 CFM 116 LG  13       16          0
0AMB000508  PLATE, OIL PUMP ASSY W/OPS          13       16          0
1BZB002222  MOTOR CASE MACHINING, FRAME 2       0        16          0
1BZB003105  ROTOR CASE MACHINING                0        16          0
1BZB003122  MOTOR COVER MACHINING               0        16          0
1BZB003126  IRA BEARING COVER MACHINING         0        16          0
1BZB003128  IRA DISCHARGE COVER MACHINING       0        16          0
1BZB003205  ROTOR CASE MACHINING                0        16          0
1BZB003224  OUTLET CASE MACHINING               0        16          0
1BZB003226  IRA BEARING COVER MACHINING         0        16          0
1BZB003228  IRA DISCHARGE COVER MACHINING       0        16          0
1TA0915D    CASING, OUTLET(4.0/2.8)             0        32          0
```

Comment: Kevin thanks for your answer, but I am stuck at the point where I cannot make the the column named 'backlog' that has all item before this weeks date.

Comment: Oh I must have missed something, I'll have a look

Comment: @user955485 I changed the query which now includes the backlog.

Comment: Hey Kevin the number I need in the backlog and weeks column(s) are the number of items for that week. I think my question was not clear enough. I do not need the SDM_Demand week as the number in the columns backlog and weekly dates. what I trying to figure out is how to get the number of items for that particular week in the weeks and backlog column.

Comment: I changed some things around in your code and I is working like expected. Thanks.